# RegEx to detect OS version in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Getting the information from the HTTP User-Agent header using navigator.userAgent in JavaScript we get things like this (using different OS and browsers):

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12"

"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.44 Safari/534.7"

"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009030423 Ubuntu/8.10 (intrepid) Firefox/3.0.7"

"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021906 Firefox/3.0.7"

"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_6; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/528.16"
```

As you can see the OS version is the group of numbers before the third semicolon;

I need a javascript regex to get his numbers.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not an answer, so I'll comment: Remember to take any information in the `USER-AGENT` header with a grain of salt. Not only *can* it be faked, in some communities, it's likely to be. For a general-purpose website, though, you can largely ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regex match approach is going to be awkward here.  As you can see from your own samples, the version details for Firefox on Ubuntu are in a different place entirely.  You could use a simple split regex which will separate the string into different parts:

```
// Split on ;, ( or ), removing the white-space at either side 
var parts = navigator.userAgent.split(/\s*[;)(]\s*/);
```

Result:

```
["Mozilla/5.0", "Windows", "U", "Windows NT 6.1", "en-US", "AppleWebKit/534.7", "KHTML, like Gecko", "Chrome/7.0.517.44 Safari/534.7"]
```

The added benefit here is that you can extract the information you need without an overly complicated regular expression.  A simple conditional from here could tell you where the OS/version data is stored, followed by further processing to extract just the version number.  For example:

```
var result;
if (/^Linux/.test(parts[3]))
    result = parts[6].split("/").pop(); // "8.10" (Ubuntu)
else
    result = parts[3].split(" ").pop(); // "6.1" (Win 7)
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/p6Uzc/**

Further conditionals will be required for other browsers/systems (like browsers on mobile phones).  For example, Opera 10 on Windows 7 has a user agent string containing:

> Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; en) Presto/2.6.30 Version/10.63

Also remember that the USER AGENT string can be spoofed to look completely different or contain different information.

Comment: This will give me "Windows NT 6.1" instead of "6.1" for example

Comment: @Jonathan: updated my answer to expand.  The varying results from different browser/os combinations make a regex match approach very awkward.

Comment: Yeah didn't work for me.
OS version detected: AppleWebKit/536.5,   
User-Agent: 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5"

Comment: Great answer, but it doesn't work for MacOS. Here's an updated version:

http://jsfiddle.net/russellsayshi/pQQq9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
/(?:[^;]+;){2}.*?([\w\.]+);/g
```

Within the first match you'll find the OS version

Comment: This won't work for the Linux sample User Agent string provided by the Gecko engine, where the version number is closer to the end of the string.

Comment: The [\w\.] matches letters, numbers underscores and dots, but you can use \S instead as someone else suggested.
@Andy E: why it won't work? I've tried it and it works well

Comment: mck89: For the 3rd sample string in @Jonathan's question, it returns `["Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64;"]`.  Aside from the obvious, `x86_64` isn't the versions number of the OS (it's actually Ubuntu 8.10).

Comment: I think it wont work for Linux because the real version for Linux OS is not before the third semicolon. With your suggestion it will give us 'x86_64' witch is not the real version.

Comment: Ahhhh now i understand. Anyway i tkink you should use it and then if the versione matches `/x\d+_\d+/g` look for `/ubuntu\/(\S+)/gi` to take the ubuntu version

Answer (score 0):

The following will grab all the non-space characters right in front of the third semicolon and put it in the first group:

```
.*?;.*?;.*?(\S+);
```

Depending on what you want to include you can change the \S to include only the characters you are interested in.

Comment: using split() i get this: ["", "6.1", " en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12"] So I think it will put it in the second group [1] Right?

Answer (score 0):

Solution that works for me:

```
// finding OS
function findOS(){

    var OS_Name = navigator.appVersion;
    if (OS_Name.indexOf("Win") != -1) {
        // 64bit or 32bit version
        if (test(/\sx64|\sx86|\swin64|\swow64|\samd64/i)) {
            // if 64 bit Windows
        } else {
            // if 32 bit Windows
        }
    } else if (OS_Name.indexOf("Mac") != -1
        || OS_Name.indexOf("X11") != -1
        || OS_Name.indexOf("Linux") != -1
        || OS_Name.indexOf("SunOS") != -1   ) {
        //if it's OS that is not Windows
    }
}

function test(regex) {
    return regex.test(navigator.userAgent);
}
```

Very elegant way to detect *which OS client* is using and is it *64 or 32bit*.